# How can I sort the values in array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
$my_array_to_sort=[['id'=>19381881,'value'=>4],['id'=>19970711,'value'=>65],['id'=>19231029,'value'=>18]];
```

How can I sort this array to get an array like this ?

(sort by 'value',high to low );

```
  $my_sorted_array=[
                      ['id'=>19970711,'value'=>65], 
                      ['id'=>19231029,'value'=>18],
                      ['id'=>19381881,'value'=>4],
                     ];
```

Comment: [Lots of ideas here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+sort+2d+array) you are looking to sort a 2D array.

Comment: Please check the PHP manual, then google, then SO search before posting on SO. All three would have gotten you the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this function to sort every multidimensional array by one of it's columns :

```
function sortArrayBy($array , $column_name,$sort=SORT_DESC){
  foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
   $column[$key]  = $row[$column_name];
  }
  array_multisort($column, $sort, $array);
  return $array;
 }
```

Call it like this :

```
<?php  $my_sorted_array = sortArrayBy($my_array_to_sort,'value') ; ?>
```